# Elastic search condition

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Hello i am confuse in condition in elastic search. Code works fine if parameter is not empty if parameter is not given to method how can i handle this bool query.

```
def elastic_search(category=None):
    client = Elasticsearch(host="localhost", port=9200)
    query_all = {
        'size': 10000,
        'query': {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "category": category
                        }
                    }]
               },
        }
    }
    resp = client.search(
        index="my-index",
        body=query_all
        )
    return resp
```

Comment: You need to `match_all` if category is None... simply build your query conditionally depending on what the value of category is

Comment: @val Can you please suggest some code snip that will be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `match_all` if category is None... simply build your query conditionally depending on what the value of category is.

Something like this should do

```
def elastic_search(category=None):
    client = Elasticsearch(host="localhost", port=9200)

    query_all = {
        'size': 10000,
        'query': {}
    }

    if category is None:
        query_all['query']['match_all'] = {}
    else:
        query_all['query']['bool'] = {
             "filter": [
               {
                 "match": {
                   "category": category
                 }
               }
             ]
        }

    resp = client.search(
        index="my-index",
        body=query_all
        )
    return resp
```